What is the best possible security for authentication of entity?
The classical security for authentication is computational provided by RSA or EC based signatures. With the advent of new PQ schemes the security claims are upgraded though nothing is proved. So the point is, which authentication schemes are provable and which can be considered as most secure for authentication. Is there an analogue of Perfect Secrecy for authentication?

No, asymmetric algorithms generally are build upon mathematical problems. These problems are considered mathematically hard, but it is not clear if P = NP. If that's the case then any of these hard problem may be solved in polynomial time.
Furthermore, it is unproven if there are any faster ways of solving a problem such as the RSA problem or the Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm Problem (ECDLP). And the PQC rely just as much on the algorithm being computationally hard to solve.
In short: no, there is no such thing as perfect security for authentication. Actually, since asymmetric encryption also relies on these kind of problems, there is no perfect secrecy for asymmetric encryption either.


With the advent of new PQ schemes the security claims are upgraded though nothing is proved.

Which claims would that be? The main claim of these algorithms is that they are resistant against quantum-cryptanalysis. They may be less secure than classical algorithms as less classical cryptanalysis has been performed on them.
